# Read txt file in dataframe by splitting on tab and space and newline

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing issue in reading txt file into panda dataframe. I have data like this in txt file.

```
97ebd0c6680f7c0535dbfdead6e51b4b    dd65fa250fca2833a3a8c16d2cf0457c
ed180d7daf639d936f1aeae4f7fb482f    4725c39a5e5f4c188d382da3910b3f3f
3e12208dd0be281c92a6ab57d9a6fb32    24  2016-01-01 13:37:23

92c3ac9251cc9b5aab90b114a1e363be    c077e0297639edcb1df6189e8cda2c3d
191a180f0a262aff3267775c4fac8972    82cc4851f9e4faa4e54309f8bb73fd7c
b05379ac3f9b7d99370d443cfd5dcc28    2   2016-01-01 09:47:54
.....
```

Please note data is separated by tabs, newlines and spaces. There are 8 columns in total. What I have written is this. This solution works on tabs and newlines but fail on spaces.

```
data = [i.strip('\n').split('\t') for i in open('./training_data/order_data/order_data_2016-01-01')]
```

it produces something like this.

```
[['97ebd0c6680f7c0535dbfdead6e51b4b','dd65fa250fca2833a3a8c16d2cf0457c',
  'ed180d7daf639d936f1aeae4f7fb482f','4725c39a5e5f4c188d382da3910b3f3f',
  '3e12208dd0be281c92a6ab57d9a6fb32', '24', '2016-01-01 13:37:23'],
 ['92c3ac9251cc9b5aab90b114a1e363be', 'c077e0297639edcb1df6189e8cda2c3d', 
  '191a180f0a262aff3267775c4fac8972', '82cc4851f9e4faa4e54309f8bb73fd7c',
  'b05379ac3f9b7d99370d443cfd5dcc28', '2', '2016-01-01 09:47:54']
```

please note it seprated on tabs and newlines but failed on spaces.

```
'2016-01-01 13:37:23'
```

I have also tried this but doesn't work.

```
data=pd.read_fwf('./training_data/order_data/order_data_2016-01-01', sep=' ')
data = re.split(r'\t', str(data))
```

can you please suggest an update in this code? It generates list which i can convert to data-frame. but if you have solutions which generates data-frame directly, it will be helpful.
Thank you

Comment: @ajax1234 Can you please help me by updating your code.

Comment: What is your goal? A dataframe with 8 columns? Are you sure you want the date a time seperate? Pandas Timestamps consist of date and time.

Comment: no, my goal is a dataframe with 8 columns. '2016-01-01 09:47:54' should be seprate like this. '2016-01-01',  '09:47:54'

Comment: From your input data it's difficult to tell what is actually a line, as we can't just copy and paste what you have. But try  `pd.read_table('your_file', header=None, sep='\s+')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split`:

```
import re, pandas
new_data = list(filter(None, [re.split('\s+', i.strip('\n')) for i in open('filename.txt')]))
result = pandas.DataFrame(new_data)
```

`new_data` Output:

```
[['97ebd0c6680f7c0535dbfdead6e51b4b', 'dd65fa250fca2833a3a8c16d2cf0457c'], ['ed180d7daf639d936f1aeae4f7fb482f', '4725c39a5e5f4c188d382da3910b3f3f'], ['3e12208dd0be281c92a6ab57d9a6fb32', '24', '2016-01-01', '13:37:23'], ['92c3ac9251cc9b5aab90b114a1e363be', 'c077e0297639edcb1df6189e8cda2c3d'], ['191a180f0a262aff3267775c4fac8972', '82cc4851f9e4faa4e54309f8bb73fd7c'], ['b05379ac3f9b7d99370d443cfd5dcc28', '2', '2016-01-01', '09:47:54']]
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for answering but your solution make one column of two entities like that .['97ebd0c6680f7c0535dbfdead6e51b4b', 'dd65fa250fca2833a3a8c16d2cf0457c']
I want each entry in separate column. 8 columns in total

Comment: @shahidhamdam How do you want to pad entries with less than eight items? With empty lists?

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.read_table('your_file', header=None, sep='\s+')
```

this solutions worked as it will encounter all single space+multispace(tab).